# What is wrong with this simple HTTP-GET request to a python file on my website?

Tags: python, html, http

I was following this tutorial (section Simple URL Example:Get Method)
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm

I copied this code they give to a file hosted in my website (cPanel hosting):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

However, it doesn't work as you can check by doing the HTTP request http://eatpopcorns.com/hello_get.py?first_name=ZARA&last_name=ALI

All it does is show the content of the python file...

Comment: Sure you have a CGI enabled web server, with Python interpreter installed? Based on the response, your web server serves this file as a simple text, and will not threat as CGI at all. 

Normally the server treats things as CGI scripts _only_ if it is in a certain directory: *All the CGI Programs to be executed by the HTTP server are kept in a pre-configured directory. This directory is called CGI Directory and by convention it is named as /var/www/cgi-bin.*

Comment: Oh, and one non-related comment: It is 2017, probably time to retire CGI scripts. CGI was a great tool in 1995, but nowadays have no advantage except of its low initial complexity. 

CGI comes with both performance and security issues. Of course, "your mileage may vary" :)

Answer (score 0):

I looked in the godaddy help and apparently the server doesn't support phython, I thought all the servers supported it... no problem I will learn and use PHP